# Issue with for loop and if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using Javascript and Openlayers library in order to style a vector feature on the map.
I have written the following script:

```
var gidS = response[Object.keys(response)[Object.keys(response).length - 1]] // get the data from json obj
// ADD STYLING - DIFFERENT COLORS FOR WHAT IS COMPLETE  
var styleContext = {
        getColor: function (feature) {
            var objectKeys = Object.keys(gidS); // use objectkeys to loop over all the object properties //use it to get the length
            for (var i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i++){
                    //alert(i);

                   //////////////////
                   if(gidS[i][1]=="MT"){
                        //alert(gidS[i][1]);
                        return "green"; 
                    }
                    else if(gidS[i][1]=="IRU"){
                        alert(gidS[i][1]);
                        return "#780000"; //no images on this line
                    }
                    /////////////////////// 
            }
        }
};
```

If I run the script without the if conditions (between the slashes) then I get a correct incremental value of i based on the maximum length of gidS. 
But when I include the if statements for some reason the variable i doesn't increment. It remains 0.

**EDITED**

The getColor function is executed later like this

```
// define Style
                var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
                    fillColor: "${getColor}",
                    fillOpacity:"1",
                    strokeColor: "${getColor}",
                    strokeOpacity: "1",
                    strokeWidth: 8,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    pointRadius: 8

                }, {
                    context: styleContext
                });
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot.
D.

Comment: The `return` statement returns from the function immediately.

Comment: Why do you need `i` to increase to it's maximum potential?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean @bloodyKnuckles

Comment: Why not return out of the function as soon as you get a color? Do you use `i` later? Or do you want to make sure every element is checked?

Comment: I need to know that every element is checked.

Comment: if you want to check all elements, then do not return only 1 value only on your function. try call that function that return all color for gids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the color in a variable, for example: `color`, and return it at the end of the function:

```
getColor: function (feature) {
    var color = '';
    var objectKeys = Object.keys(gidS); // use objectkeys to loop over all the object properties //use it to get the length
    for (var i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i++){
        if(gidS[i][1]=="MT"){
            color = "green"; 
        }
        else if(gidS[i][1]=="IRU"){
            color = "#780000"; //no images on this line
        }
    }
    return color;
}
```

By looping through every property of the object, and then returning, you're effectively getting the last possible matching "MT" or "IRU", if any. If you return out of the function as soon as you find a match, then your getting the first possible matching "MT" or "IRU".

For example, given the set: `[[435,'IRU'],[34324,'MT'],[343,'MT']]` My method will return `green`, and your method will return `#780000`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using your code actually returns everything green color. That shouldn't be like this.

Comment: What does the object `gidS` look like?

Comment: indeed, we dont know how to input that variable into your object :)

Comment: The gidS looks like this: [[435,IRU],[34324,MT],[343,MT]...]

Comment: By looping through every property of the object, you're effectively getting the last possible matching "MT" or "IRU". If you return out of the function as soon as you find a match, then your getting the first possible matching "MT" or "IRU".

Comment: well there is no place to put the color, so i assume, in that function you only return 1 value for 1 request on 1 specific part in gidS ?

Comment: The sample set you provided has both possibilities *"IRU"* and *"MT"*. What determines which color ought to be returned in any particular context? What relationship do the numbers (435, 34324, and 343) have with the contexts *"fillColor"* and *"strokeColor"*? Or is it the *"defaultStyle"* that is the determining context?

Answer (score -1):

don't use the return, it immediately stop after used .

try this altough i dont know the gidS.

```
if(gidS[i][1]=="MT"){
   gidS[i]['color']='green';                     
}
else if(gidS[i][1]=="IRU"){
   gidS[i]['color']='#780000';                       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But where should I place the return?

Comment: @dkar: It depends. What exactly are you trying to do. Depending on what you want your code is either correct to use return or incorrect. Since you say you don't want it like that we can assume it's incorrect. But you don't mention what the result should be.

Comment: @slebtman I have edited my answer and added the part where the getColor function is called. This code runs and gives a color to each line feature (street) on the map.

Comment: @dkar looking at your revised question, why not calling that function  after you set your properties of gids? so your function doesn't required to return anything, it just check all your element and set the correct color.

Comment: @downvoter  please tell me why you choose to down-vote me? in case i stumble upon this issue again.